# How to sum value of array if some values are same?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array

```
Array (
    [0] => 1995,17500
    [1] => 2052,17500
    [2] => 2052,17500
    [3] => 2236,30000
    [4] => 2235,15000
    [5] => 2235,40000
);
```

I have exploded the value with comma ,.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {

      $newar = explode(',', $value);
}
```

So I have similar first value i.e $newar["0"]. For example 2235 and 2052. And I would like to have sum of second value i.e $newar["1"].

How can I achieve following result with PHP.

```
Array (
   [0] => 1995, 17500
   [1] => 2052, 35000
   [2] => 2036, 30000
   [3] => 2235, 55000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array key/index based and use `array_key_exists` to check if the key already exists. If so sum the value, if not create the key. This is not the exact result you want, but it's neater.

```
$newar = []; //New Array

foreach($array as $value) {
     $explArr = explode(',', $value);

     if(array_key_exists($explArr[0], $newar)){ //Check if the key already exists
        $newar[$explArr[0]] += $explArr[1]; //Sum value to existing key
     } else {
        $newar[$explArr[0]] = $explArr[1]; //Create key
     }
}
```

Your result array will look like this:

```
Array (
   [1995] => 17500
   [2052] => 35000
   [2036] => 30000
   [2235] => 55000
)
```

Comment: [You can better use `isset($newar[$explArr[0]])` instead of using another php function `array_key_exists($explArr[0], $newar)`](https://3v4l.org/TRLqW)

Comment: @Uchiha Because? Micro-optimizing?